# Trouble with references in Python (trees)

Tags: python, pointers, reference, tree

I'm trying to remove all subtrees that only contain zeros. My code is below. Right now, running removeFailures on the root node does not modify the tree at all (doing preorder traversal before and after gives the same result).

I think it is because when I say "root is None" I'm not actually modifying root, I'm simply creating a temp variable names root possibly? If that's the case how could I go about fixing this? Wouldn't this reasoning work in Java?

```
    # Ex.
    #           4                      4
    #        /     \                /      \
    #       1       3              1        3
    #       / \    / \     -->    /       /  \
    #      0   0  4  6           0       4   6
    #     /\  /\                / \
    #    3 5 0  0              3  5


    class TreeNode:
        def __init__(self, data, left=None, right=None):
            self.data = data
            self.left = left
            self.right = right


    def removeFailures(root):
        if root is None:
            return True

        removeLeft = removeFailures(root.left)
        removeRight = removeFailures(root.right)
        if root.data == 0 and removeLeft and removeRight:
            root = None
            return True
        return False


    def preorder(root):
        print root.data
        if root.left:
            preorder(root.left)
        if root.right:
            preorder(root.right)

    example = TreeNode(4)
    example.left = TreeNode(1, TreeNode(0, TreeNode(3), TreeNode(5)), TreeNode(0, TreeNode(0), TreeNode(0)))
    example.right = TreeNode(3, TreeNode(4), TreeNode(6))
    preorder(example)
    print '*************************'

    removeFailures(example)

    preorder(example) #TODO
```

Answer (score 0):

To check that all nodes in a tree contain zero, you will have to loop over each of those nodes. A possibility is to create an `__iter__` method to find all the nodes in a tree, and then the `any` builtin function can be applied to determine if they are all equal to zero. Lastly, a simple recursive method can check the left and right children and remove if necessary.

For simplicity in creating the tree, `kwargs` is being used to build the structure in-place without implementing a rotate method or a long sequence of assignment statements:

```
class Tree:
  def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    self.__dict__ = {i:kwargs.get(i) for i in ['left', 'right', 'val']}
  def __iter__(self):
    yield self.val
    yield from ([] if self.left is None else self.left)
    yield from ([] if self.right is None else self.right)
  @staticmethod
  def remove_empty_trees(_t):
    if not any(_t):
       return None
    _t.remove_trees()
    return _t
  def remove_trees(self):
    if not any([] if self.left is None else self.left):
       self.left = None
    else:
       self.left.remove_trees()
    if not any([] if self.right is None else self.right):
       self.right = None
    else:
       self.right.remove_trees()
```

---

```
#           4         
#        /     \    
#       1       3 
#       / \    / \  
#      0   0  4  6
#     /\  /\            
#    3 5 0  0
t = Tree(val=4, left=Tree(val=1, left=Tree(val=0, left=Tree(val=3), right=Tree(val=5)), right=Tree(val=0, left=Tree(val=0), right=Tree(val=0))), right=Tree(val=3, left=Tree(val=4), right=Tree(val=6)))
new_tree = Tree.remove_empty_trees(t)
print(print(new_tree.left.right))
```

Output:

```
None
```

To handle the case where the entire tree contains nodes of zero, the `staticmethod` provides an additional check.

Answer (score 0):

After recursively calling `removeFailures()` on the child nodes, it is necessary to set them to `None` if they have been successfully removed:

```
def removeFailures(root):
    if root is None:
        return True

    removeLeft = removeFailures(root.left)
    removeRight = removeFailures(root.right)

    # Check if successfully removed children
    if removeLeft:
        root.left = None
    if removeRight:
        root.right = None

    if root.data == 0 and removeLeft and removeRight:
        root = None
        return True
    return False
```

Output:

```
4
1
0
3
5
0
0
0
3
4
6
*************************
4
1
0
3
5
3
4
6
```

Setting the node itself to `None` is not enough, because the parent node still holds a reference to it. Therefore, it is required to set all references to that node to `None` to properly remove it.